# Loading a BufferedImage from a png and preserving transparency

Tags: java, graphics

I'm essentially stacking multiple `JPanels` on top of each other on a `JFrame` to simulate how layers would work in an image editing program. Each has a `BufferedImage` of a png file that has transparency. As far as I understand, in order to make the `BufferedImage` have the same transparent areas as the png, one has to make the `BufferedImage` of type 2 or TYPE_INT_ARGB.

This is my `ImagePanel` code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{

    String directory;

    public ImagePanel (String str)
    {
        directory = str;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(directory));
            BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            g.drawImage(newImage, 0, 0, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The original loaded `BufferedImage` is of type 13, while the changed one is of type 2 (which is correct). However after the change, no images actually display on the frame.

Here's the main if needed:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1100, 580);
        frame.setLocation(dim.width/2 - frame.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2 - frame.getSize().height/2);
        frame.add(new ImagePanel("/resources/BackImage.png"));
        frame.add(new ImagePanel("/resources/FrontImage.png"));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Call setOpaque on the panel and pass it false

Comment: In your code, you’re creating and painting a blank image

Comment: setOpaque was the first thing that I turned to and it doesn't resolve the issue. As for the image, it definitely does paint an image if the code pertaining to the "newImage" is removed. The primary issue is that I need to use the newImage to make a version of the old image that is transparent.

Comment: If the source image isn’t transparent, then making a new image (with transparency) and paint the original onto it isn’t going to make any difference - your source image needs to be transparent to start with

Comment: The source image is transparent – which is why the issue is so perplexing to me in the first place.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't have the line of code that paints the old image onto the new image that supports alpha. That explains your second comment – apologies for the confusion. Regardless, even with this line included, transparency on the source image is not preserved.

Comment: That’s because the source is not transparent - at a level Java understands - without the source image it’s impossible to know what to suggest

Comment: Type 13 is TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED.  I’m pretty sure a PNG with an indexed colormap can still have transparency.

Comment: @VGR Does done one want to post the image in question? 

Comment: So, I did a test. I took a transparent PNG (`TYPE_INT_ARGB`) and painted to a `BufferedImage` setup to use `TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED` and the transparency was lost.  I used the same test and instead of outputting to `TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED` I outputted to `TYPE_INT_ARGB` and the transparency was preserved. One critical step I took was to make sure that before I painted the source image to the destination image, I cleared the `Graphics` context so it was completely transparent.  I might not be possible for Java to render a image of `TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED` with transparency

Comment: This indexed PNG displays fine in Swing, including with transparency: https://imgur.com/a/xuHPN  I was able to place it in an ImageIcon directly, and I was able to draw it to a new BufferedImage with type TYPE_INT_ARGB, without losing transparency in either case.  Thus, I am inclined to suspect that Moribus’s images may not be transparent.